# Shade smooth not uniform problem

Tags: shaders, smooth

the shade smooth isn't uniform i mean that isn't the same on all parts[image]

the circled parts are fine but the others aren't and i don't know why, its the same object mirrored and rotated and there aren't any mark sharp edges,
someone knows how to fix that?

Comment: Hello, make sure that the normals are correctly oriented (in Edit mode select all and press Shift N), also try a right click > Shade Smooth in Object mode, with Auto Smooth activated in the Data panel > Normals. If it still doesn't work please share the wheel object

Comment: I check the normals and everything's fine, here's the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=L1spjWp0" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/L1spjWp0/) , thanks for the help :)

Comment: You have unapplied, non-uniform scale.  Autosmooth angle is measured in object space.  Apply scale.

Comment: Oh perfect you right! i just need to apply scale

Answer (score 3):

To fix this problem i just needed to apply scale, thanks to everybody for the support :)